# Which packages contain IPsec implementations and algorithms that use it for encryption?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption, ipsec

Which package contains the implementation of IPsec and which package contains the implementation of encryption algorithms that IPsec uses for encryption? I need to use custom crytographic algorithms in IPsec, so I need to edit the implementations of these packages.

Comment: The IPsec implementation including any cryptographic algorithm is in the kernel.

Comment: Ahmad Darwish, welcome to Unix SE! Unless you work with a bunch (100+) of gifted cryptographers who would review your implementation, rolling your own crypto is very very DANGEROUS.

Comment: thanks for your advice Deer Hunter, I know this is dangerous but the main idea is understanding the implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux and most other unices, IPsec and other network protocols up to the transport layer are implemented in the kernel. There are additional userland tools that handle [key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Key_Exchange); [several implementations exist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Key_Exchange#Implementations).

The cryptographic algorithms are in [`crypto`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.8.2/crypto/). The network protocols are spread around [`net/ipv4`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.8.2/net/ipv4/), [`net/ipv6`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.8.2/net/ipv6/) and [`net/xfrm`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.8.2/net/xfrm/).